# Need to Run batch script in UNIX server and display the output through vbscript

Tags: unix, vbscript, putty

I am currently developing the new VBScript to execute the Shell (through Putty software) in UNIX server,

```
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Exec D:\Putty.exe hostname -l username -pw password 1.sh
```

I am getting `connection refused` error.

when I run the below command without my script (`1.sh`)

```
shell.Exec D:\Putty.exe hostname -l username -pw password
```

Connection is getting established without any issues.

Also, I just wanted to extract the output, once extracted, the session should get closed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work in `putty.exe`. Putty has however a dedicated program to do these kind of things, it's called `plink.exe` - there you can pass commands and read the output just as you would expect, and your example should work just like you specified it.

```
PuTTY Link: command-line connection utility
Release 0.63
Usage: plink [options] [user@]host [command]
       ("host" can also be a PuTTY saved session name)
Options:
  -V        print version information and exit
  -pgpfp    print PGP key fingerprints and exit
  -v        show verbose messages
  -load sessname  Load settings from saved session
  -ssh -telnet -rlogin -raw -serial
            force use of a particular protocol
  -P port   connect to specified port
  -l user   connect with specified username
  -batch    disable all interactive prompts
The following options only apply to SSH connections:
  -pw passw login with specified password
  -D [listen-IP:]listen-port
            Dynamic SOCKS-based port forwarding
  -L [listen-IP:]listen-port:host:port
            Forward local port to remote address
  -R [listen-IP:]listen-port:host:port
            Forward remote port to local address
  -X -x     enable / disable X11 forwarding
  -A -a     enable / disable agent forwarding
  -t -T     enable / disable pty allocation
  -1 -2     force use of particular protocol version
  -4 -6     force use of IPv4 or IPv6
  -C        enable compression
  -i key    private key file for authentication
  -noagent  disable use of Pageant
  -agent    enable use of Pageant
  -m file   read remote command(s) from file
  -s        remote command is an SSH subsystem (SSH-2 only)
  -N        don't start a shell/command (SSH-2 only)
  -nc host:port
            open tunnel in place of session (SSH-2 only)
  -sercfg configuration-string (e.g. 19200,8,n,1,X)
            Specify the serial configuration (serial only)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Let me try to download the PLINK and will update you. Please confirm that do we have any other options to do connect the UNIX server without external softwares.

Comment: `plink.exe` is part of the normal putty installation, so it is not really "external software" if you consider putty.

Comment: @msiva1989: was this answer helpful? If so, please consider voting on it, or accepting it. Thanks.